# Int Showing as Long Odd Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, int, game-center

I am trying to send an int in my iphone game for game center multiplayer.

The integer is coming up and appearing as an odd long integer value rather than the expected one.

I have this in my .h:

```
typedef enum
{
 kPacketTypeScore,
} EPacketTypes;

typedef struct
{
 EPacketTypes type;
 size_t size;
} SPacketInfo;

typedef struct
{
 SPacketInfo packetInfo;

 int score;
} SScorePacket;
```

Then .m:

Sending data:

```
scoreData *score = [scoreData sharedData];

  SScorePacket packet;
  packet.packetInfo.type = kPacketTypeScore;
  packet.packetInfo.size = sizeof(SScorePacket);
  packet.score = score.score;

  NSData* dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:&packet length:packet.packetInfo.size];
  NSError *error;
  [self.myMatch sendDataToAllPlayers: dataToSend withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
  if (error != nil)
  {
   // handle the error
  }
```

Receiving:

```
SPacketInfo* packet = (SPacketInfo*)[data bytes];

 switch (packet->type)
 {
  case kPacketTypeScore:
  {
   SScorePacket* scorePacket = (SScorePacket*)packet;

   scoreData *score = [scoreData sharedData];

   [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You: %d Challenger: %d", score.score, scorePacket]];

   break;
  }

  default:
   CCLOG(@"received unknown packet type %i (size: %u)", packet->type, packet->size);
   break;
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You: %d Challenger: %d", score.score, scorePacket->score]]; // Note: scorePacket.score
```

You're were trying to print a pointer-to-the-scorePacket, not the score in-the-packet.

Comment: Ahh of course, that seems obvious now but I get this: error: request for member 'score' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Almost what you said it was `scorePacket->score`

Answer (score 0):

Needed scorePacket->score rather than scorePacket. Printing the wrong thing.